# media query will never be rendered in scss

Tags: css, sass

I've started using **Sass** in my projects and I've come across a peculiar problem that I never faced using vanilla **CSS**.

For some reason my `media` queries will never get rendered (even when placed at the bottom of the file and the criteria is met); the browser will *always* render the original properties and their values unless I use `!important` (which I don't want to do because it's bad practice and just unnecessary).

I've tried putting the `media` queries at the top of the file and still nothing.

This is my code:

```
#content .result{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 725px;
    border-right: $border;
    vertical-align: top;
}

// this will be shown in Chrome developer tools when the viewport reaches 1120 pixels or less, 
// but all the new properties will be crossed out and the browser will decide to use the old
// values instead - i have no idea why
@media screen and (max-width: 1120px){
    .result{
        // will all be crossed out
        display: block;
        width: auto;
        border-right: none;
    }
}
```

Now I don't know if I've missed something completely obvious (unlikely, I've used media queries hundreds of times), or this is just a quirk of **Sass**, but any help is greatly appreciated. Cheers.

**EDIT:** As you can see, I have no other styles defined. *And*, the media query is in fact almost 200 lines after the original property declarations.

[image]

Comment: does your page include the `meta` viewport?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Yes

Comment: is that style _all_ the style you have or are you including other css files? Maybe are you repeating some declarations?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan No other CSS files are being added. I've checked the developer tools and there are no dual declarations.

Comment: Seems to be working alright - https://codepen.io/painotpi/pen/poyowKQ

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan see edit.

Comment: @painotpi see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a more specific rule `#content .search-results` that wins over  `.search-results`.

Either you remove the `#content` selector from the first rule or you add it inside the mediaquery so both the selectors can have the same specificity.

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea that media queries played favourites.

Comment: As a side note, in the question you should put the _actual_ relevant code, which is different.

Comment: Minified it for ease of view. My file is almost 600 lines, so I didn't want to include things I thought might stray away from the topic at hand. Accidentally left out something important - will edit now. Cheers

Comment: Ref sheet of sorts: https://specifishity.com/